Solution to "basic" ODE which came up during research
So during my research this ODE came up, but I'm not very experienced in explicitly solving ODEs.  Does this one have a known explicit solution
$$
t\,y^{\prime}(t) = (bt+k)y(t)
$$
where $b,k$ are non-zero constants.

$y’/y = b +k/t$, and integrate.

Write your equation as $\frac{y'\left(t\right)}{y\left(t\right)}=\frac{bt+k}{t}=b+\frac{k}{t}$.
Upon integrating both sides with respect to $t$, we get $\ln\left(y\left(t\right)\right)=bt+k\ln\left(t\right)+c$ where $c$ is an integration constant.
Exponent both sides, so that $y\left(t\right)=e^{bt+k\ln\left(t\right)+c}$.
This can be rewritten more elegantly with a new constant $d$ as $y\left(t\right)=d e^{bt+k\ln\left(t\right)}$
Simplifying, we arrive at $y\left(t\right)=d e^{bt} t^k$
Edit: Added integration constant and simplified further. Thank you for the comments.

Don’t forget the constant of integration.

$e$ to the power of $ln(t)$ is just a linear function. You might want to make it clear in the solution.
